# Logstash output to Iothub using https

Tags: logstash, azure-iot-hub

Any one using IoT hub as an output in logstash. I know that there is a plugin logstash-output-iothub plugin to leverage logstash to ship to IoT hub.

```
output {
  iothub {
    connection_string => "{set your iot hub connection string}"
  }
}
```

This by default connect to 8883 port.

8883 is blocked in our firewalls, and i wanted to use port 443.

How to leverage this communication using https ?

Can i use something like this ?

```
output {
  iothub {
    connection_string => "{https://set your iot hub connection string}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look at the source. As per line https://github.com/tac0x2a/logstash-output-iothub/blob/efbbd07eb3ddb822acb8f24c92088efc27ebc4e2/lib/logstash/outputs/iothub.rb#L35 it appears to be fixed to MQTT. You might try changing it to use MQTT over web sockets (IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT_WS) and, since it is using the Azure IoT SDK under the covers, it *should* work. MQTT over web sockets uses port 443.